# nuendo4 as a music production program?

Tags: music, production, nuendo4, drum, machine

I know it's been a while, I'm proud to note though. that I'm sorted with nuendo4 as far as sound design is concerned.

It is a steinberg product and the company is known for it's cubase roots. I'm used to propellerheads'reason, where can I find the drum machine?

Answer (score 2):

Nuendo doesn't have any drum machine or instruments.  If you add the NEK it will give you the additional music tools that Cubase includes.  Otherwise, you will need to add plugins for instruments.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Nuendo 3 before moving to a Mac where I'm now using Pro Tools. Although its been some time, I recall having a drum editor in Nuendo. Its much like a piano roll but optimized for drums which is probably the closest to a drum machine in Nuendo natively. If you're looking for a drum machine as a sampler then I believe you're out of luck.

Cubase is optimized for Music while Nuendo is optimized for post production, although I believe Nuendo is built over Cubase. I feel that Nuendo is overkill for just music production but can be extremely useful for post production. There's no saying that Nuendo can't be used for music production but I just feel that too many things would get in the way.

Comment: Recently, Steiny split the music and post features in Nuendo.  It used to come with all of Cubase's features.  Now you have to buy an add-on (the NEK referred to above) to get full music features.

Comment: I see. That just makes Nuendo less capable for music production. But if you're going to juggle as a studio for both sound design and occassionally music, getting the NEK to complete it probably isn't a bad idea since there is such a heavy investment in Nuendo.